# Find inside coordinates of polygon in tile based map

Tags: java, awt, coordinates, polygon, java-2d

If I have all of the outer edges of polygons in a list how would I go about finding the inside coordinates??  To make matters simple I drew the following image to represent the problem:

[image]

I need to find the inside of 'buildings' in a tilebased game.

- **outside walls** - grey shaded cells.
- **inside building** - light blue cells.

In the event the building is not fully shown in view (right building) I have solved the issue by adding the entire green section (-1,-1, 0,-1, etc.) into the list.

Without following some insane if search tree I have no idea how to solve this.  I am posting here for some tips, code, or psuedo code.  Any help is so appreciated.  Thanks so much! :)

---

***EDIT***

@Andrew Thompson:  I think I miswrote my situaton.  This is not like the duplicate you linked to.  I don't have the image.  The excel drawing I did above was just an example.  For that example:

I have a list containing the brown values:
ie. {"1,1", "2,1", "3,1", "1,2", etc.}

And I need a corresponding list of the blue values: ie. {"2,2", "2,6", "3,6", "4,6", etc.}

Comment: Have you any code that models the game and the buildings.

Comment: it is a mmorpg and the building layer is stored in a text file in a syntax like so (0,34,34,45,0,...) where each number represents a tile number.  When I parse the map on the client side I was going to add a tile to the list if it == XX or XY, etc.  So to answer your question, not not really any semblance of a way to define it a building.

Comment: Opencv has some useful functions to work with so called contours. Maybe this helps to get some ideas. Is your data model pixel- or vector-oriented?

Comment: it is a tilebased map just like i drew above so hopefully that will make my life a tad easier.  I will look at Opencv. ty.  Would love to write my own code though.  I don't like imports :)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson I have clarified my question as your linked post is not a duplicate (unfortunately for me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I toyed around with the A* algorithm this week. There may be other solutions to your request, but since I already have the code, it was just a matter of adapting it to your needs. However, for your specific requirement you could also simply use a **primitive flood-fill algorithm** and classify the cells this way, see the method in the algorithm code.

The [A* algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) finds a path from a given start to a given goal. In your case the start is the goal, which means it's a reference point that classifies an "outside" cell. From there on we search for everything that we can traverse.

I left the path finding code for you in the example, maybe it's of use for your further needs.

Here's the code:

Demo.java

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;


public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // create grid like in the example
        int cols = 9;
        int rows = 9;

        Grid grid = new Grid( cols, rows);

        // create walls like in the example
        grid.getCell( 1, 1).setTraversable( false);
        grid.getCell( 2, 1).setTraversable( false);
        grid.getCell( 3, 1).setTraversable( false);
        grid.getCell( 1, 2).setTraversable( false);
        grid.getCell( 3, 2).setTraversable( false);
        grid.getCell( 6, 2).setTraversable( false);
        grid.getCell( 7, 2).setTraversable( false);
        grid.getCell( 8, 2).setTraversable( false);
        grid.getCell( 1, 3).setTraversable( false);
        grid.getCell( 2, 3).setTraversable( false);
        grid.getCell( 3, 3).setTraversable( false);
        grid.getCell( 6, 3).setTraversable( false);
        grid.getCell( 6, 4).setTraversable( false);
        grid.getCell( 7, 4).setTraversable( false);
        grid.getCell( 1, 5).setTraversable( false);
        grid.getCell( 2, 5).setTraversable( false);
        grid.getCell( 3, 5).setTraversable( false);
        grid.getCell( 4, 5).setTraversable( false);
        grid.getCell( 5, 5).setTraversable( false);
        grid.getCell( 7, 5).setTraversable( false);
        grid.getCell( 8, 5).setTraversable( false);
        grid.getCell( 1, 6).setTraversable( false);
        grid.getCell( 5, 6).setTraversable( false);
        grid.getCell( 1, 7).setTraversable( false);
        grid.getCell( 2, 7).setTraversable( false);
        grid.getCell( 3, 7).setTraversable( false);
        grid.getCell( 4, 7).setTraversable( false);
        grid.getCell( 5, 7).setTraversable( false);

        // find traversables
        // -------------------------

        AStarAlgorithm alg = new AStarAlgorithm();

        Cell start;
        Cell goal;

        // reference point = 0/0
        start = grid.getCell(0, 0);
        Set<Cell> visited = alg.getFloodFillCells(grid, start, true);

        // find inside cells
        for( int row=0; row < rows; row++) {
            for( int col=0; col < cols; col++) {

                Cell cell = grid.getCell(col, row);

                if( !cell.traversable) {
                    cell.setType(Type.WALL);
                }
                else if( visited.contains( cell)) {
                    cell.setType(Type.OUTSIDE);
                } 
                else {
                    cell.setType(Type.INSIDE);
                }

            }
        }

        // log inside cells
        for( int row=0; row < rows; row++) {
            for( int col=0; col < cols; col++) {
                Cell cell = grid.getCell(col, row);
                if( cell.getType() == Type.INSIDE) {
                    System.out.println("Inside: " + cell);
                }
            }
        }

        // path finding
        // -------------------------

        // start = top/left, goal = bottom/right
        start = grid.getCell(0, 0);
        goal = grid.getCell(8, 8);

        // find a* path
        List<Cell> path = alg.findPath(grid, start, goal, true);

        // log path
        System.out.println(path);

        System.exit(0);

    }

}
```

Type.java

```
public enum Type {

    OUTSIDE,
    WALL,
    INSIDE,

}
```

Cell.java

```
public class Cell implements Cloneable {

    int col;
    int row;
    boolean traversable;
    Type type;

    double g;
    double f;
    double h;

    Cell cameFrom;

    public Cell( int col, int row, boolean traversable) {
        this.col=col;
        this.row=row;
        this.traversable = traversable;
    }

    public double getF() {
        return f;
    }

    public double getG() {
        return g;
    }

    public double getH() {
        return h;
    }

    public void setTraversable( boolean traversable) {
        this.traversable = traversable;
    }

    public void setType( Type type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Type getType() {
        return this.type;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return col + "/" + row;
    }
}
```

Grid.java

```
public class Grid {

    Cell[][] cells;

    int cols;
    int rows;

    public Grid( int cols, int rows) {
        this.cols = cols;
        this.rows = rows;
        cells = new Cell[rows][cols];

        for( int row=0; row < rows; row++) {
            for( int col=0; col < cols; col++) {
                cells[row][col] = new Cell( col, row, true); 
            }
        }
    }

    public Cell getCell( int col, int row) {
        return cells[row][col];
    }

    /**
     * Get neighboring cells relative to the given cell. By default they are top/right/bottom/left. 
     * If allowDiagonals is enabled, then also top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right cells are in the results.
     * @param cell
     * @param allowDiagonals
     * @return
     */
    public Cell[] getNeighbors(Cell cell, boolean allowDiagonals) {

        Cell[] neighbors = new Cell[ allowDiagonals ? 8 : 4];

        int currentColumn = cell.col;
        int currentRow = cell.row;

        int neighborColumn;
        int neighborRow;

        // top
        neighborColumn = currentColumn;
        neighborRow = currentRow - 1;

        if (neighborRow >= 0) {
            if( cells[neighborRow][neighborColumn].traversable) {
                neighbors[0] = cells[neighborRow][neighborColumn];
            }
        }

        // bottom
        neighborColumn = currentColumn;
        neighborRow = currentRow + 1;

        if (neighborRow < rows) {
            if( cells[neighborRow][neighborColumn].traversable) {
                neighbors[1] = cells[neighborRow][neighborColumn];
            }
        }

        // left
        neighborColumn = currentColumn - 1;
        neighborRow = currentRow;

        if ( neighborColumn >= 0) {
            if( cells[neighborRow][neighborColumn].traversable) {
                neighbors[2] = cells[neighborRow][neighborColumn];
            }
        }

        // right
        neighborColumn = currentColumn + 1;
        neighborRow = currentRow;

        if ( neighborColumn < cols) {
            if( cells[neighborRow][neighborColumn].traversable) {
                neighbors[3] = cells[neighborRow][neighborColumn];
            }
        }

        if (allowDiagonals) {

            // top/left
            neighborColumn = currentColumn - 1;
            neighborRow = currentRow - 1;

            if (neighborRow >= 0 && neighborColumn >= 0) {
                if( cells[neighborRow][neighborColumn].traversable) {
                    neighbors[4] = cells[neighborRow][neighborColumn];
                }
            }

            // bottom/right
            neighborColumn = currentColumn + 1;
            neighborRow = currentRow + 1;

            if (neighborRow < rows && neighborColumn < cols) {
                if( cells[neighborRow][neighborColumn].traversable) {
                    neighbors[5] = cells[neighborRow][neighborColumn];
                }
            }

            // top/right
            neighborColumn = currentColumn + 1;
            neighborRow = currentRow - 1;

            if (neighborRow >= 0 && neighborColumn < cols) {
                if( cells[neighborRow][neighborColumn].traversable) {
                    neighbors[6] = cells[neighborRow][neighborColumn];
                }
            }

            // bottom/left
            neighborColumn = currentColumn - 1;
            neighborRow = currentRow + 1;

            if (neighborRow < rows && neighborColumn >= 0) {
                if( cells[neighborRow][neighborColumn].traversable) {
                    neighbors[7] = cells[neighborRow][neighborColumn];
                }
            }

        }


        return neighbors;
    }

}
```

AStarAlgorithm.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * A* algorithm from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm
 */
public class AStarAlgorithm {

    public class CellComparator implements Comparator<Cell>
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(Cell a, Cell b)
        {
            return Double.compare(a.f, b.f);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Find all cells that we can traverse from a given reference start point that's an outside cell.
     * Algorithm is like the A* path finding, but we don't stop when we found the goal, neither do we consider the calculation of the distance.
     * @param g
     * @param start
     * @param goal
     * @param allowDiagonals
     * @return
     */
    public Set<Cell> getFloodFillCells(Grid g, Cell start, boolean allowDiagonals) {

        Cell current = null;

        Set<Cell> closedSet = new HashSet<>();

        Set<Cell> openSet = new HashSet<Cell>();
        openSet.add(start);

        while (!openSet.isEmpty()) {

            current = openSet.iterator().next();

            openSet.remove(current);

            closedSet.add(current);

            for (Cell neighbor : g.getNeighbors(current, allowDiagonals)) {

                if (neighbor == null) {
                    continue;
                }

                if (closedSet.contains(neighbor)) {
                    continue;
                }

                openSet.add(neighbor);
            }

        }

        return closedSet;

    }

    /**
     * Find path from start to goal.
     * @param g
     * @param start
     * @param goal
     * @param allowDiagonals
     * @return
     */
    public List<Cell> findPath( Grid g, Cell start, Cell goal, boolean allowDiagonals) {

        Cell current = null;
        boolean containsNeighbor;

        int cellCount = g.rows * g.cols;

        Set<Cell> closedSet = new HashSet<>( cellCount);

        PriorityQueue<Cell> openSet = new PriorityQueue<Cell>( cellCount, new CellComparator());
        openSet.add( start);

        start.g = 0d;
        start.f = start.g + heuristicCostEstimate(start, goal);


        while( !openSet.isEmpty()) {

            current = openSet.poll();

            if( current == goal) {
                return reconstructPath( goal);
            }

            closedSet.add( current);

            for( Cell neighbor: g.getNeighbors( current, allowDiagonals)) {

                if( neighbor == null) {
                    continue;
                }

                if( closedSet.contains( neighbor)) {
                    continue;
                }

                double tentativeScoreG = current.g + distBetween( current, neighbor);

                if( !(containsNeighbor=openSet.contains( neighbor)) || Double.compare(tentativeScoreG, neighbor.g) < 0) {

                    neighbor.cameFrom = current;

                    neighbor.g = tentativeScoreG;

                    neighbor.h = heuristicCostEstimate(neighbor, goal);
                    neighbor.f = neighbor.g + neighbor.h;

                    if( !containsNeighbor) {
                        openSet.add( neighbor);
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        return new ArrayList<>();
    }

    private List<Cell> reconstructPath( Cell current) {

        List<Cell> totalPath = new ArrayList<>(200); // arbitrary value, we'll most likely have more than 10 which is default for java

        totalPath.add( current);

        while( (current = current.cameFrom) != null) {

            totalPath.add( current);

        }

        return totalPath;
    }

    private double distBetween(Cell current, Cell neighbor) {
        return heuristicCostEstimate( current, neighbor); // TODO: dist_between is heuristic_cost_estimate for our use-case; use various other heuristics
    }

    private double heuristicCostEstimate(Cell from, Cell to) {

        return Math.sqrt((from.col-to.col)*(from.col-to.col) + (from.row - to.row)*(from.row-to.row));

    }

}
```

The result for the inside cell logging is

```
Inside: 2/2
Inside: 7/3
Inside: 8/3
Inside: 8/4
Inside: 2/6
Inside: 3/6
Inside: 4/6
```

The result for the path from 0/0 to 8/8 is

```
[8/8, 7/7, 7/6, 6/5, 5/4, 5/3, 5/2, 4/1, 3/0, 2/0, 1/0, 0/0]
```

I wrote an editor for this in JavaFX, will come up as a blog post soon, if you are interested. Basically your grid will look like this:

[image]

Where

- black cells = walls
- green cells = traversable cells
- blue cells = path from start to end
- white cells = cells inside walls

The numbers are the ones from the A* algorithm:

- top/left = g (from start to current cell)
- top/right = h (from current cell to goal)
- center = f = g + h

And like this if you don't allow diagonal movement:

[image]

But that's just off-topic :-)

Comment: wow holy crap, what a post :)  I should have mentioned though, I already have movement completed.. the purpose is to find the inside walls and that's it :p  would love to link to your blog post on my game, Kisnard Online, which you just helped with your answer ;)

Comment: also unfortunately this does not work if 0,0 is a wall.  It seems the origination point needs to be outside.. which will not always be the case.  I guess I can just check to ensure the origination point is not a wall, but i have no way to check it is not an 'inside'

Comment: You can use any node as origination point, e. g. the player's start point. You have to determine what's an outside point first, or otherwise an algorithm could as well see your map inversed and have an inverse result.

Comment: Example: A wall from top/left to bottom/right is a valid situation in your case. But what's the inside and what's the outside? the lower/left area or the upper/right area?

Comment: The image i drew pretty accurately represents my case.  The right side building is not fully shown because the character is not within view.  Buildings are all polygons and have walls touching at NSEW not NW, etc.  The only thing I know is a list of coodinate points that represent walls.  I need to know the inside of each building (preferably as seperate lists).

Comment: Well, you could use the flood-fill algorithm on the walls directly and determine afterwards the characteristics of the surrounding grid cells. However, still what I wrote above applies. If you scroll your grid down by 3 cells, the right-bound walls become a line from top to right and you wouldn't know what's inside and what's outside.

Comment: if it is that case it is irrelevant.  Sorry i tried to simplyify so this could be benefitial to multiple people and not specific.  It is for my game... the whole purpose is to paint this inside of buildings as black if a player is not looking through a window, inside the building, or if the door is closed.  The walls always remain as walls, but the inside needs to be painted black (or a roof).

Comment: If you want to do it properly, then you need to classify the areas explicitly, at least the walls and the insides. Otherwise your problem isn't solvable. As I said, a Rectangle with a diagonal line is a valid situation for your problem. You can't possibly know which triangle of that rectangle is the inside and which one's the outside.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77924/discussion-between-kisnardonline-and-roland).

Comment: Sorry, no time to chat, I'm off for the weekend. One thing I'd like to add: You don't need to classify the insides if you classify the walls as north/south/east/west walls. That way you can easily find out e. g. if you have a north wall, that the upper cell is outside and the lower cell is inside.

Comment: I have decided the path of least resistance (classify the inside walls).  Thanks so much for all of the help.  Now I will just strip it down a bit since I don't need the A* part.  I've given you the bounty! :)

Answer (score 0):

I find this a really interesting post :) I find refreshing to try to resolve these apparently simple problems, it's really refreshing.

I've come up with a simple algorithm that could work with rectangular areas. It's just on the paper, untested, but I'll try to explain it as better as I can to see you can convert it to actual code.

My idea is to perform horizontal sweeps to the area, and have some kind of status machine to recognize possible blue tiles. The process would be more or less the following:

- We read a row. There, we look for **three or more consecutive brown tiles**. If we happen to find that, we store two values in a data variable: the column of the first one (using the first square of your image, column 1) and the column of the last one (same example, 3).
- We read another row. And there, before looking for consecutive rows, we look into the 1 and 3 columns. *If they're brown*, we look at the color of the tiles between them (in this example, tile [2,2]). *If those tiles are not brown*, then we store that in a data structure, where we keep track of the potentially blue tiles.
- We read another row. Again, we look into the 1 and 3 columns. And again, they are brown. Again, we look to the color of the tiles between them, and this time they're brown. Good, this is a closed square! We put all those tiles we had stored as potentially blue, ([2,2]) to **actual blue**.
- We read another row. Again, we look into the 1 and 3 columns. Oh, no luck. They're not brown anymore. We pop the 1 and 3 values, we won't look there anymore as long as no consecutive rows are found again.

I have a meeting right now, if I have some time I'll write a simple pseudocode (just for fun) with the checks in every point of the loop. If I have some more time, I'll think on some kind of improvement to detect non-square areas. I think it can be pretty simple, something like looking for consecutive brown tiles intersecting with marked columns (by marked, I mean for example the 1 and 3 in the sample run above) and adjusting the new marked limits for that area accordingly.

I'll try to consider as well mountain-like areas where you detect two different areas in the upper part of the map, but they end up joining up in the lower part. I never thought this was a simple problem, after all :) Meanwhile, I hope I've been able to provide you some insight.

Answer (score 0):

It's really a [floodfill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) problem.

Do you know the coordinates of the vertices of the polygons ? Then there are algorithms that will compute the floodfill faster. And you won't have to decide which part is a building and which part isn't.

If you don't know the vertices, you will have to do a "real" floodfill :

If there is one tile you know is not in a building, just floodfill there and the rest is the buildings.

If you don't know that, then you can keep floodfilling until there is no more tiles, and you will have divided the area into zones.

Then actually you can't tell the buildings from the rest without making some assumptions. For example, suppose your area is divided in two by a brown line : which one is the building ?

Maybe you know the ground has more tiles than any building ? That two buildings can't touch each other ? That they are convex ?

Comment: I have no way of identifying which tile is not in a building (without limiting my tilemapping)

Comment: You will have to make assumptions then. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Actually it will be easiest to use the coordinates of the vertices of the polygons. You drew them yourself right ? So you should know them ?

Comment: Lets reduce the problem... I have a list of coordinate points(and nothing more). If X number of points form a polygon, I need a corresponding list of the inner points of said polygon.

Comment: If said points are vertices (not all the points on the edge of the polygons like in your example) then like I said you can use polygon filling algorithms, for example http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/java/Polygon/Filling/FillPolygon.htm (I just googled it but finding an algorithm should be easy). If you do have the vertices, and you know which vertices belong to which polygon, you should update your question accordingly, because the problem is different (and easier, I think).

Comment: As mentioned I only know the full list of coordinate points.  I have no knowledge of vertices.